# didSet detection on ANY field?

Tags: c#, reflection, setter

I've done some searching (and mostly finished C# in depth) but haven't come across what I'm looking for.

I'm curious though if there is a way (hacky is ok!) that I can get a generic notification or hook from ANY set operation on a class.

The reason is I am working on a framework that saves the state of the app as a class. And when the state changes, I want a notification from it.

Setting up a `didSet` (i.e. firing an alert in every setter call) on every possible field is tedious overkill. Do you know of any way I can get hook for any time a field is changed on a class?

**Update 1**

A great suggestion by @thehennyy was to look at [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/product/why). Here is a video which highlights what it does: https://vimeo.com/143656221

**Update 2**

Open source [MIST](https://github.com/mathtone/MIST) suggested by @Mattias Åslund.

Comment: Do you mean fields or properties?

Comment: Well you create a property for a field. I can create properties that fire the events I need, but that is why Im curious if theres a generic way I can do it instead of having to create a specific property for each field just to get a notification of a change.

Comment: When you access the field directly there is no way. When you use a property to access it, sure you can implement code in the properties setter/getter. I suggest to have a look at PostSharp, there is no built in solution to do this.

Comment: Interesting Ill take a look at that.

Swift has a cool `didSet` and `willSet` feature but it too relies on implementation per field.

Comment: Ive read now many questions including [Fody](https://github.com/Fody). This thing seems to implement `PropertyChanged` at compiletime. So no work for you. After this inject, you  can hook up on Event. I have zero expierience with that thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MIST](https://github.com/mathtone/MIST) on github. It will do exactly what you are looking for and is free.

Comment: I was an initial reviewer for it and have submitted some code for it; mostly unit tests. So it wasn't that hard to find it... ;)

Comment: Well but you have to implement Attributes on each Property. I thout OP wanted to avoid that?

Comment: Are there similar things like this for Java and Swift too?

Comment: @lokusking No, you can make the class implicit notify for properties too

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Thanks for clarification! Just had a quick look on the Syntax, and obviously i missed that part

Comment: I'm going to try my hand at implementing this and will accept once I've got it working :)

Comment: I didn't post this requirement (so I won't hold it against the answer) but it looks like this uses .Net 4.0. I am trying to use this for Unity which I believe limits things to .Net 2.0 :(

Comment: I dont remember how far back Mathtone compiled it for, but ask him on github.

Comment: I dont know Unity, but maybe this link about how to use c# 6 in unity can be of help too: https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/overview